# Quarkus. Load test and memory utilisation

Tags: quarkus

I created a **simple** service that performs **4 HTTP calls and 4 db calls** to collect some data and pass it to the `HTTP` response as `JSON`.

As I start the application (**native, no docker**), I see it consumes `7MB`, sometimes `15MB` sometimes **30MB**. Good.

As I start loading testing it,
 sending 1 request every 10 milliseconds, in total **100 requests**.

I noticed the memory consumption goes to **200MB** right away. Then after 5-6 more tests to **400MB**. (As much is Spring Boot version of it takes).

**Question is**: is it expected to be like that?

Should it be trying be minimalist (for the native v of it) about the memory and clean after itself, at least after n minutes or so? Is there are settings for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on GraalVM native images, but from a quick local test with a "Hello world" app, I'm seeing similar numbers to you. It seems if you don't set a limit on max heap size, one will be chosen automatically (not sure about criteria). You can start your app with `-XX:+PrintGC` to see memory activity. Then, you can experiment with `-Xmx` (e.g. `-Xmx32m` to set max heap size to 32 MB) -- the more memory you give to the app, the less frequent garbage collection cycles will be. This article shows some more interesting GC options: https://e.printstacktrace.blog/graalvm-heap-size-of-native-image-how-to-set-it/

Comment: correct. By default native image will have -Xmx to infinity (heap can grow unlimited), and -Xmx (new generation size) to 256M. Currently, until the young generation is exceeded, no GC is triggered. So without config in a powerful environment you'll eventually see memory grow to 256M at least.

Comment: If you think about it, in a constrained environment, like a docker container with way less resources, this strategy makes more sense by default.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for providing more details!